# pypyodbc Can't refer to column names using SQL Server Localdb

Tags: python, sql-server, localdb

Total Python noob here. I am writing a script against a sql server local db and cannot call values based on the column name.

```
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\database;integrated security = true')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM [students].[dbo].[users]")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print (row.username)
cnxn.close()
```

returns AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'username'

```
print (row)
```

dumps the data as expected. And modifying the code to:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT username FROM [students].[dbo].[users]")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
x=0
for row in rows:
    print (row.cursor_description[x][0])
cnxn.close()
```

returns username for each record.

Why can I not call row.username?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `print (row["username"])`

[pypyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pypyodbc) does not support column properties as [pyodbc](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc) does, only a column collection that you can get by index or it's header name.

pyodbc uses `row.attribute` syntax, pypyodbc uses `row["attribute"]` syntax.

Comment: pypyodbc uses lower case for attribute names